# Can the result of lower_bound(From C++ STL) be assigned to an integer type variable?

Tags: c++, stl

I recently started using the C++ STL, and today I tried out the `lower_bound` function in my code. But unfortunately, I got the error:

```
cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >' to 'long long int' in assignment|
```

Here is my code

```
lli n;
cin >> n;
lli k;
cin >> k;

vector<lli> v;
lli store;
for(lli i = 0;i < n;i++)
{
    cin >> store;
    if(store < k)
        v.push_back(store);
}

sort(v.begin(),v.end());

lli paths = 0;
for(lli i = (lli)v.size()-1;i >= 0;i--)
    paths = paths + lower_bound(v.begin(),v.begin()+i-1,v[i]-k);

cout << paths;
```

If you guys say that an iterator type variable can't be added to an integer type variable,this code:

https://github.com/sampritipanda/IOI_Repository/blob/master/ZCO/2013/CHEWING.cpp
uses the result of lower_bound to be assigned to an integer type variable, through the line:

```
int j = lower_bound(gum.begin() + i, gum.end(), K - gum[i]) - (gum.begin() + i);
```

Please advice where I'm going wrong.

Note: `lli` stands for `long long int` which has already been defined using a macro.

If you want any clarifications, please ask.

Comment: No it doesn't assign an iterator to an integral variable. Read carefully, and match parenthesis.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile - looks like you're missing some typedefs as well as the usual includes and a main() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't assign an iterator to an integral variable.

```
lower_bound(gum.begin() + i, gum.end(), K - gum[i]) - (gum.begin() + i);
```

will return `std::vector<int>::difference_type`

The best you can do in your case is:

```
paths = paths + (lower_bound(v.begin(),v.begin()+i-1,v[i]-k) - v.begin());
```